# Best practice for permanently storing key-value pairs on mobile web?

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, trigger.io

I'm **saving images** on my mobile web app once they're downloaded the first time. I don't want to have to store this in a table, because the same user may have different images saved on different devices so data persistence would be an issue. Using [TriggerIO's saveURL](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/file.html#saveurl) I'm given back the local location of the downloaded image, but to use it in the future it must be stored in a permanent location.

The best solution I know to this would be to store it as a **key-value pair** in an HTML5 **web database** and query the database to see if there is a local copy before downloading a remote copy, but because this can happen up to 50x on a single page, I think 50 queries could slow down my app. Is there a better option?

An enhancement to this option would be to load all of the KVPs to an object and persist saves to the database. Thoughts?

Comment: You are contradicting yourself - on one hand you *do not want* to store it in table. On other hand, you *want* to store it in HTML5 database, which **is** SQLite. What gives? BTW, SQLite is very much capable of storing arbitrary key/value pairs in a table.

Comment: 50 queries to a WebSQL database will be really quick - I wouldn't worry about it. There's also forge.prefs, which may be slower because it goes to native code. Storing all the values in a hash is a good option if you do hit performance problems, as you say.

Comment: @mvp My bad — to clarify, I meant a remote table in my database.

Comment: @JamesBrady my current solution uses localStorage and seems to be working well, but I'm wondering when it's cleared on iOS and Android. If it is never cleared, why not just do that?